# Two select options in different table cells don't work

Tags: html, css, forms

So I have these `<select><option>`s which I put in two different table cells and no matter what the second one doesn't work the way it should. It kinda shows up as the select object on the page but I can't proceed any further actions (choose any option from the dropdown).
Code:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    //... other cells
    <form action="./users.php" method="POST"> 
      <td class="sex">
        <select name="sex">
          <option value="m">Male</option>
          <option value="f">Female</option>
          <option value="o">Other</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="language">
        <select name="language">
          <option value="french">French</option>
          <option value="german">German</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works fine in the snippet you provided. What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: the `<select name="sex">` works fine for me as well, but the `<select name="language">` just appears as the select bar and i can't choose any option, it's not clickable at all.